# To be able to: physical ability or polite form?

Tags: modal-verbs, politeness

Is it possible to use *to be able to* for polite inquiry:

> Will you **be able to** walk the dog this afternoon?

Or it's not how it can be used?

Comment: Using "be able to" is fine, though you might want to use "Would" instead of "Will".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is a polite form of asking for a favor. It leaves the door open for the person you are asking to refuse politely.

> Will you be able to walk the dog this afternoon?
>
> No, I'll be visiting my sister on the other side of town.

(an actual, physical reason)

> No, I'm sorry I won't.

(an unstated reason that you won't try to dig deeper into)

"be able to" can be used for either of the senses you ask in the question title.

[Able](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/able) (MW, adjective, definitions 1 & 2)

> having enough power, resources, or skill to do something "Are you able to swim?"
>
> having the freedom or opportunity to do something "I'll come when I'm able."